# Windows 7. My disc is not blank

Tags: windows-7, dvd-burning

I am new here. I'm here to ask a question. How I can make my DVD Windows 10 DVD to blank DVD, so I can burn windows 10 21h1 iso to my DVD? It will be appreciated if I will get a solution to my question! It's fine if I had to buy a new DVD as it's not blank. Any solutions?

[image: Here is my screenshot of not having a blank DVD.]

That's the screenshot I had. Please, someone!

Comment: Windows 10 typically is installed from a USB Key. Get an 8 GB USB Key and put the Windows 10 ISO on this key and make it bootable. Install with this key.

Comment: You need to buy a new blank DVD, except if the DVD is classified as "DVD-RW", where RW = ReWritable, and you have a DVD-burner with the same classification. All other DVD's can only be written once, and you cannot erase the data which is on them.

Comment: If the ISO in question > 4.7GB then you would need a  blank Dual Layer DVD media and your DVD burner should support Dual Layer Disc which most of them do. Use a good app like Nero or BurnAware Free on Windows for example to burn ISO to  a blank DVD disc.

Comment: @1NN Please don't post answers as comments.

Answer (score 1):

> How I can make my DVD Windows 10 DVD into a blank DVD so I can burn the Windows 10 21H1 ISO to my DVD?

Unfortunately, most CD/DVDs (including commercial DVDs) cannot have their existing data rewritten. That requires special rewritable (RW) media to have been used initially to create the disc.

> It's fine if I have to buy a new DVD.

You will likely need to buy additional blank DVD discs if you want to burn the ISO you have. The estimated sizes for Windows 10 21H1 are approximately:

- 3.9GB (32-bit)
- 5.4GB (64-bit)
- 7.37 ("Both")

For the 32-bit version of Windows 10 21H1, single-layer DVDs (which can typically hold up to 4.7GB) are fine. For the 64-bit version or the version combining both, you will need dual-layer DVDs (which can typically hold up to 8.5GB).

> Any solutions?

You can also (theoretically) use a bootable USB key created with the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool. Size requirements would still apply (i.e. you would need a 4GB USB key for the 32-bit version of Windows 10 21H1 and an 8GB USB key for the other versions).

Note that your PC would need to be capable of booting from USB to use this method (many are). The option or settings for booting from a USB key are often accessible in the BIOS/EFI settings of the computer.

---

*As a side note, I recently installed Windows 21H1 on an older PC via USB key after having a terrible time trying to get an ISO version to burn correctly. Personally, I am very attached to old-school media, set-up discs and ISOs in general, but I was really suprised (and at that point grateful) regarding how easy the USB key was to create and use.*

---